# Box-plot for each month: reordering

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a data frame named `MyData`. Let's say it looks like this:

```
GreekMonth <- c("Ir","Fe","Mr","Ar","Ma","In","Il","Au","Se","Ok","No","De")

SomeValue <- c(rep(c(1,3,5),4), rep(c(2,4,6),4), rep(c(7,8,9),4))

MyData <- data.frame(MONTHS=rep(GreekMonth,3), MY_VALUE=SomeValue)
```

I tried to make a box-plot for each month. So I wrote:

```
library(ggplot2)

MyBox <- ggplot(MyData, aes(x=MONTHS, y=MY_VALUE))

MyBox + geom_boxplot()
```

Of course months are ordered alphabetically.

[image]

So, I wrote:

```
MyData$MONTHS <- factor(MyData$MONTHS, labels = GreekMonth)
```

and then:

```
MyBox2 <- ggplot(MyData, aes(x=MONTHS, y=MY_VALUE))

MyBox2 + geom_boxplot()
```

As you can see, months are ordered correctly, but with the wrong values.

[image]

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
MyBox + 
  geom_boxplot()+
  xlim(GreekMonth)
```